# Debug SharePoint Hosted and Provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app, apps-development, autohosted, cloud-business-apps

I am fighting with issues on apps ( SharePoint Provider & Hosted)models .Can any one guide me in knowing how do debug the apps.And what should i need to install if pre-requisite exists for debugging

Comment: The APP  will be deploying on developer site template only while development , where you can debug in the same way how to debug a web application/console application by putting breakpoints.

Comment: Where you have hosted your web project for Provider hosted app?